# Parsing sub-element's attribute directly into Go struct

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing, openstreetmap

In parsing XML with Go, how can I read a nested element's attribute directly into my struct?

My XML looks like this below. It is part of the OpenStreetMap format:

```
<way id="123" >
        <nd ref="101"/>
        <!-- Lots of nd elements repeated -->
        <nd ref="109"/>
</way>
```

I have

```
type Way struct {
    Nodes []NodeRef `xml:"nd"`
}
```

with

```
type NodeRef struct {
    Ref int `xml:"ref,attr"`
}
```

but I would like to be able to do

```
type Way struct {
    Nodes []int `???`
}
```

directly.

The documentation on [Unmarshalling](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal) didn't help me. I've tried using `xml:"nd>ref,attr"` but that fails with "chain not valid with attr flag".

Please see the below example code. [Run the code in Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/HHO7SbTVcn)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    data := `
        <way id="5090250" >
        <nd ref="822403"/>
        <nd ref="21533912"/>
        <nd ref="821601"/>
        <nd ref="21533910"/>
        <nd ref="135791608"/>
        <nd ref="333725784"/>
        <nd ref="333725781"/>
        <nd ref="333725774"/>
        <nd ref="333725776"/>
        <nd ref="823771"/>
      </way>
    `

    r := strings.NewReader(data)
    way, err := ReadWay(r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not read", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println(way)
}

// I'd like to get rid of this nested struct.
type NodeRef struct {
    Ref int `xml:"ref,attr"`
}

type Way struct {
    ID int `xml:"id,attr"`
    // How can I write all <nd ref="123"/> directly into Nodes []int?
    Nodes []NodeRef `xml:"nd"`
}

func ReadWay(reader io.Reader) (Way, error) {
    var way Way
    if err := xml.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&way); err != nil {
        return way, err // Why can't I return nil, err?
    }
    return way, nil
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't do that directly. The common pattern to bypass the XML structure is to implement the `xml.Unmarshaler` interface. Here is an example:

```
type Way struct {
    ID    int 
    Nodes []int
}

func (w *Way) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var payload struct {
        ID    int `xml:"id,attr"`
        Nodes []struct {
            Ref int `xml:"ref,attr"`
        } `xml:"nd"`
    }   

    err := d.DecodeElement(&payload, &start)
    if err != nil {
        return err 
    }   

    w.ID = payload.ID
    w.Nodes = make([]int, 0, len(payload.Nodes))

    for _, node := range payload.Nodes {
        w.Nodes = append(w.Nodes, node.Ref)
    }   

    return nil 
}
```

Here, the `payload` variable is modeled after your XML data, while the `Way` struct is modeled as you want it to be. Once the payload is decoded, you can use it to initialize the `Way` variable as you want…

*Side note:* `// Why can't I return nil, err?`

You can't return `nil` because `Way` isn't either a pointer or an interface, thus `nil` isn't a valid value for it.

Comment: For future reference the documentation about this is here: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshaler